# Chisel persist value in module until new write

Tags: scala, chisel

I have created a basic module that is meant to represent a unit of memory in Chisel3:

```scala
class MemristorCellBundle() extends Bundle {
    val writeBus = Input(UInt(1.W))
    val dataBus = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val cellBus = Output(UInt(8.W))
}

class MemCell() extends Module {
    val io = IO(new MemCellBundle())

    val write = Wire(UInt())
    write := io.voltageBus

    val internalValue = Reg(UInt())
    // More than 50% of total voltage in (255).
    when(write === 1.U) {
        internalValue := io.dataBus
        io.cellBus := io.dataBus
    } .otherwise {
        io.cellBus := internalValue
    }
}
```

What I want is for it to output the `internalValue` when the `write` bus is logic LOW, and change this value with logic HIGH. My understanding of Chisel is that the register can persist this `internalValue` between clock cycles, so that this basically acts as a single unit of memory.

I'm doing it in this way as part of a larger project. However when writing a unit test I am finding that the 'read-after-write' scenario fails.

```scala
class MemCellTest extends FlatSpec with ChiselScalatestTester with Matchers {
    behavior of "MemCell"
    it should "read and write" in {
        test(new MemCell()) { c =>
            c.io.dataBus.poke(5.U)
            c.io.write.poke(0.U)
            c.io.cellBus.expect(0.U)
            // Write
            c.io.dataBus.poke(5.U)
            c.io.write.poke(1.U)
            c.io.cellBus.expect(5.U)
            // Verify read-after-write
            c.io.dataBus.poke(12.U)
            c.io.write.poke(0.U)
            c.io.cellBus.expect(5.U)
        }
    }
}
```

The first two expectations work just as I would expect. However, when I try to read after writing, the `cellBus` returns to `0` instead of persisting the `5` that I had written previously.

```
test MemCell Success: 0 tests passed in 1 cycles in 0.035654 seconds 28.05 Hz
[info] MemCellTest:
[info] MemCell
[info] - should read and write *** FAILED ***
[info]   io_cellBus=0 (0x0) did not equal expected=5 (0x5) (lines in MyTest.scala: 10) (MyTest.scala:21)
```

Clearly the register is not keeping this value, and so `internalValue` reverts to `0`. But why does this happen, and how would I be able to create a value that can persist?

Comment: Registers' values only get updated on the subsequent clock cycle, so make sure to do `step(1)` between your `poke` and `expect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drakinite's comment is correct. You need to make sure to step the clock in order to see the register latch the value. I tweaked your test to include a couple of steps and it works as expected:

```scala
  c.io.dataBus.poke(5.U)
  c.io.writeBus.poke(0.U)
  c.io.cellBus.expect(0.U)
  c.clock.step() // Added step
  // Write passthrough (same cycle)
  c.io.dataBus.poke(5.U)
  c.io.writeBus.poke(1.U)
  c.io.cellBus.expect(5.U)
  c.clock.step() // Added step
  // Verify read-after-write
  c.io.dataBus.poke(12.U)
  c.io.writeBus.poke(0.U)
  c.io.cellBus.expect(5.U)
```

Here's an executable example showing that this works (using chisel3 v3.4.4 and chiseltest v0.3.4): https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5E1rOEsYSzSUrLXZCvoyNA

Comment: Yep that was the one thing I was missing. Thanks, I'd been staring at that for too long.